# How do I broadcast my opencv camera onto a fake camera?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, camera

I am trying to use open cv to edit what my camera sees, then run it through zoom. I was thinking that maybe I could make my computer think that there were two cameras, the second being the one that connects through zoom because 2 apps cant use the same camera. How can I do this(I use windows 10)? (with detailed instructions please.)

Comment: Please state the Operating System(s) you use.

Comment: I use windows 10

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a virtual webcam device, you could take a look at https://github.com/radium226/fake-webcam.
To capture it, you could use opencv, which allows image grabbing and some pretty cool modification.

Comment: Thanks, but there isn't much documentation or instructions on this one. Can you provide more on that topic?